# Get current word in google-apps-script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Just started working with Google-apps-script and for the most part it is pretty straight forward. I am having trouble though being able to get the current word the user is typing / where the cursor is.

ie, if `|` represents my cursor and I was typing the word "hello" and was in this state `hello|` I want to return hello as a string.

I've tried many variations to get this, but can't seem to find how in the api.

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var word = doc.getCursor().getElement().asText().getText();
```

If I had `hello all|` (cursor at the end of all) I'd get the entire string 'hello all' back. I am hoping there is a way to just pick off the last element (after the last space).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gives you the last complete word:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var words = doc.getCursor().getElement().asText().getText().split(' ');
  Logger.log(words[parseInt(words.length)-2]);
}
```

This gives you the last word you where typing on:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var words = doc.getCursor().getElement().asText().getText().split(' ');
  Logger.log(words[parseInt(words.length)-1]);
}
```

You should change the split method with the correct regex to enable puntuation and enters.

Comment: Ah makes sense. I think I was in the mindset that I was only to use google api stuff. DUR it's still javascript :p. Thanks man

Comment: Hi I was looking at this, but how would you use this to get the current word you're typing on, if that word is in the middle of the line?