# Change the color of the word where the cursor is with Google Apps Script in a Google Document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps, google-docs-api

I'm trying to change the color of the word the current google docs cursor is over (when a server function is executed). I'm not sure how to do that. I saw:  [Get current word in google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076084/get-current-word-in-google-apps-script) which explained how to get the last word of the line, but that doesn't really work, this is what I have (very rough code):

```
function clientize() {///
  var t = Date.now();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  var els = doc.getElement();
  var txt = els.asText().getText().split(" ");
  var word = txt[txt.length - 1];
  var offset = doc.getOffset();
  var highlightStyle = {};
  highlightStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#FF0000';
  els.setBold(offset - 5,offset , true)
 // els.setAttributes(4,10,highlightStyle);

  return (word)
}
```

but it only gives me the last word on the line, not the word that the cursor is actually in, and also I don't know how to change the color of the word in the document once I find the text. I know I can change the color based on a certain range, but it only works on the getElement(), but how do I change the specific range of the whole word that the cursor is on?

For example, say I have the line, with the cursor:

```
hello world ho|w are you today
```

then when I activate the server function, only the word "how" should be changed to red, for example.

How is this possible????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You can do so, the trick is to get the offsets for the start & end of the current user's word.

```js
function clientize() {

  // Get the Position of the user's cursor
  var position = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();

  // Get the element that contains this Position
  var ref_element = position.getElement();

  // Get the text in the element
  var text = ref_element.asText().getText(); 

  // Get the cursor's relative location within ref_element.
  // Verify if cursor is within text elem. or paragraph elem.
  var ref_offset = position.getOffset();
  if (ref_element.getType() == DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH){

    // Cursor is at beginning or end of line
    if (ref_offset == 1){

      // Cursor is at last word. Move to the left into TEXT
      ref_offset = text.length - 1;

    }
  }

  // Get offset for current word's initial char
  var offset_first = ref_offset - text.substring(0,ref_offset).split(" ")[text.substring(0,ref_offset).split(" ").length - 1].length;

  // Get how many chars to the end of current word
  var chars_to_end;
  if (text.substring(ref_offset, ref_offset + text.length - 1).indexOf(" ") > -1) {

    // if word has a trailing space exclude it from count
    chars_to_end = text.substring(ref_offset, ref_offset + text.length - 1).indexOf(" ");

  } else {
    chars_to_end = text.substring(ref_offset, ref_offset + text.length - 1).length - 1;
  }

  // Get offset for current word's last char
  var offset_last = ref_offset + chars_to_end;

  // Define the styling attributes
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#FF00FF';

  // Apply styling to current word
  ref_element.asText().setAttributes(offset_first, offset_last, style);
}
```

**Note**: You will have to filter the returned word if it has comas or other characters trailing or preceding. 
*Hint: use regex.*
Have a look at this test [document with it's bound script](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tL-7jB6pxQnfQqZZUmMxNTvEoFHFOo4nuFtx29XTUIw/edit?usp=sharing) to see it working.

Also for reference the key function here is: [`setAttributes(startOffset, endOffsetInclusive, attributes)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text.html#setattributesstartoffset,-endoffsetinclusive,-attributes)

*Please note there is many ways to go about this, this is just one way to achieve it.*

Comment: Very nice solution, exactly what I was looking for! Except there is one extra thing I was wondering if you can help resolve: when the cursor is at the end of a word at the end of a line, then when activating the script I get the error: "Cannot find method setAttributes(number,number,object)", do you know how to fix this? I think its something to do with the getElement() actually reading the next line instead of the one the cursor is at the end of, do you know a workaround / some kind of solution?

Comment: @bluejayke Good observation. If cursor is at beginning or end of the line, then the element containing it is of type `DocumentApp.ElementType.PARAGRAPH` and thus does not have a `setAttributes(number,number,object)` method.
Given this *caveat* one needs to tweak the code to account for that possibility. 
I have edited the code and now should work as expected. :)